# Swap a sign from a positions on list

Tags: python

I have a list:

```
['E:\\Python_praktyka\\2.obj', 'E:\\Python_praktyka\\sxsxsxsxsxsx.obj', 
'E:\\Python_praktyka\\sx.obj']
```

I want to swap \ in list positions on \ and get:

```
['E:\Python_praktyka\2.obj', 'E:\Python_praktyk\\sxsxsxsxsxsx.obj', 
'E:\Python_praktyka\sx.obj']
```

How can i do it?

Comment: Do you only want it for the first and 3rd element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterating over the list and using `replace`:

```
test_str = ['E:\\Python_praktyka\\2.obj', 'E:\\Python_praktyka\\sxsxsxsxsxsx.obj',
'E:\\Python_praktyka\\sx.obj']

for i in range(len(test_str)):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        print(test_str[i].replace("\\\\", "\\"))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
E:\Python_praktyka\2.obj
E:\Python_praktyka\sx.obj
```

Comment: I was trying something similar `indices_where_replace =[0,2]` and `a=[test_str[i].replace("\\\\","\\") if i in indices_where_replace else test_str[i] for i in range(len(test_str))]`, but I don't get `//` replaced with `/`. Can you kindly point the mistake in my code?

Answer (score 1):

Use list comprehension:

```
[print(v.replace("\\\\", "\\")) for i, v in enumerate(test_str) if i % 2 == 0]
```

Output:

```
E:\Python_praktyka\2.obj
E:\Python_praktyka\sx.obj
```